# Can we use smtp with heroku without the SendGrid add-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sendgrid, add-on

I am deploying an ruby-on-rails app in Heroku.I cannot add the SendGrid add-on to the heroku account.Is there any other ways to use the email services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can simply sign up for a SendGrid account directly and then use the SMTP details. It would look like this:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}
```

There's also an example using the Mail gem, in the [SendGrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/ruby.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could use your Gmail account.
In `config > environment > production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name => ENV['GMAIL_USER_NAME'],
  :password => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}
```

Then you have to set GMAIL_USER_NAME and GMAIL_PASSWORD to Heroku configs

> GMAIL_USER_NAME should be your email address of gmail domain eg. `sample@gmail.com`